# Loop through list of unlocked items in PlayerPrefs

Tags: unity, c#, savegame

I have a list of stickers and when a player completes a level they get awarded a sticker which I save into `PlayerPrefs`. I want to be able to return the list of sprites saved into `PlayerPrefs` on the awards scene.

I have not been to loop and match the `PlayerPrefs`. I am not sure how to go about this.

```
public class StickerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Sprite> stickers = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> unlockedStickers = new List<Sprite>();

    public void UnlockSticker (int id)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("sticker", id);
    }

    public List<Sprite> LoadUnlockedSticker ()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Sprite spri in stickers)
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("sticker", i) == stickers[i])
                unlockedStickers.Add(stickers[i]);

            i++;
        }

        return unlockedStickers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each key in PlayerPrefs can store only one value, and the value has to be an integer, float, or string.

So when you do something like `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("sticker", 5);` it means "throw out whatever value you had been storing in the slot named `"sticker"` and replace it with the number 5.

If your stickers are always collected in a fixed order, then this can work - your `PlayerPrefs` value stores a count of stickers obtained so far, and you know every one with an index less than the current count has been unlocked.

If your stickers can be obtained in any order, then you need a different strategy. While you could store up to 32 independent sticker acquisitions as bitfield flags packed into a single integer, a simpler method would be to assign a distinct key to each sticker:

```
// This gives you a way to assign a serialized name for each sticker in the inspector.
// By not using the index or name of the sprite itself, this is more robust to changes.
[System.Serializable]
public struct StickerEntry {
    public string name;
    public Sprite sprite;

    // As the key, we'll add a prefix, to be sure this key doesn't collide with others we use.
    public string GetKey() {
        return string.Format("Sticker-{0}", name);
    }
}

public StickerEntry[] stickers;
public List<Sprite> unlockedStickers;

public void UnlockSticker(int id) {
    // A value of 1 means "unlocked".
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(stickers[i].GetKey(), 1);
    unlockedStickers.Add(stickers[i].sprite);
}

public List<Sprite> LoadUnlockedStickers() {
    unlockedStickers.Clear();

    foreach(var sticker in stickers) {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt(sticker.GetKey(), 0) > 0)
            unlockedStickers.Add(sticker.sprite);
    }

    return unlockedStickers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PlayerPrefs is designed as a key/value store for singular values of the types int, string and float. That means every information needs an unique key. When you have a lot of information to store, this can quickly get hard to use, slow and take a lot of unnecessary space.

Now you could go so far and implement a proper savegame system using the local filesystem. And if you want to store more than a few kByte of data, then I would urge you to do so. But working with files can have some complications, concerns and unexpected pitfalls as well, so it might take quite a lot of time to implement properly. So a compromise solution between the flexibility of savegame files and the ease of use of PlayerPrefs is to serialize the whole savegame to a string and store that string in PlayerPrefs.

Now you could of course write your own encoder and decoder for your savegame data. But fortunately Unity already got a handy class for this that might be all you need: [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html). This class can be used to convert an object to a string in JSON format, and then return that string back to an object. It doesn't support references to other objects, but it does support arrays. Here is an example (note that it does **not** inherit from `MonoBehaviour`):

```
[Serializable]
class Savegame {
    public bool[] stickerUnlocked;

    public void Save() {
        string savegameString = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("savegame", savegameString);
    }

    public static Savegame Load() {
        string savegameString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("savegame");
        return JSONUtility.FromJson<Savegame>(savegameString);
    }
}
```